# equavalant of [DllImport("wininet.dll")] for INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY in android

Tags: c#, android, cookies

I am looking for the equavalant of this DLL in android to handle INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY does anybody know this?
I most android systems the SET-COOKIES shows up only on one of our 5.1 android systems its does not show the SET-COOKIES.
This might be some security setting, but we cant find out what and where, somebody knows this?

WE have this code now, in most android systems we see the Cookie_Httponly, but in one system it does not

```
URL url = new URL (urlAddress);
String COOKIES_HEADER = "Set-Cookie";
            var connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.OpenConnection ();

            try  
            {
                var stream = connection.InputStream;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader (stream)) 
                {
                    var content = reader.ReadToEnd ();
                    Console.WriteLine(content);
                }

                var headerFields = connection.HeaderFields;

                if( headerFields.ContainsKey(COOKIES_HEADER))
                {
                    var cookiesHeader = headerFields [COOKIES_HEADER];

                    if (cookiesHeader != null) 
                    {
                        foreach (String cookie in cookiesHeader) 
                        {
                            var _c = HttpCookie.Parse (cookie) [0];
                            cookies[_c.Name] = _c.Value;
                        }               
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
```

Comment: You may wish to explain, without drawing analogies to Windows, what it is that you are trying to do.

Comment: Reference to windows is that this perfect works there, it might be handy to understand the question good